# Поиск слов и знаков препинания в тексте

Tags: java, массивы, регулярные-выражения, java-8

У меня есть задача - посчитать количество слов и знаков препинания в тексте. И т.к. я совсем еще новичок, и я просто изучаю работу регулярных выражений, я бы хотел создать массив в котором, каждое слово и каждый знак препинания - отдельные элементы массива. Я имею ввиду, что я решил эту задачу так -

```
*String[] arrayText = str.split("[[\\p{Punct}]*|[\\p{Space}]*]+"); 
System.out.println("количество слов: " + arrayText.length); 
int couttt = str.length() - str.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", "").length();
System.out.println("колличество знаков прип-ия: " + couttt);*
```

Но я бы хотел узнать, возможно ли создать массив вида `*String[] array = {"Пожалуйста", ",", "помогите", "!"}.*` , а после в цикле счетчиками из этого массива считать слова и знаки препинания ? И на сколько это хороший метод? Так же у меня проблема в написании хорошего патерна, который ищет в тексте знаки препинания. На данный момент я застрял вот на этом - `*String[] arrayText = str.split("[[\\p{Space}]*|[а-яА-Яa-zA-Z]*]*");*`

Comment: А метку языка? ;)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Метки не для того, чтобы определить язык, а чтоб отвечающим проще вопрос найти.

Comment: `\p{L}+` найдёт все буквенные слова, но, наверное, проще искать все букво-цифровые слова с помощью `(?U)[^\W_]+`, а пунктуацию можно найти с помощью `\p{P}` или (если включить математические знаки) - `[\p{P}\p{S}]`.

Comment: Я изменил код в ответе, теперь он выдаёт и совпадения, и их количество.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предлагаю такой подход: входную строку разбить по пробелам. Потом пройти по полученному массиву и найти количество знаков препинания, если элемент массива состоит не только из знаков препинания, то увеличиваем счётчик слов. А счётчик знаков препинания увеличить на найденное количество. Выглядит примерно так:

```java
    int words = 0;
    int puncts = 0;
    Matcher m;

    String str = "Пожалуйста,   em... помогите!";
    Pattern punct = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}");
    String[] arrayText = str.split("\\s");
    for (String s : arrayText) {
      int count = 0;
      m =  punct.matcher(s);
      while (m.find()) {
        ++count;
      }
      puncts += count;
      if (count != s.length()) {
        ++words;
      }
    }
    System.out.println("количество слов: " + words);
    System.out.println("колличество знаков прип-ия: " + puncts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю искать все букво-цифровые слова с помощью `(?U)[^\W_]+`, а пунктуацию — с помощью `\p{P}` или — если необходимо включить математические знаки — `[\p{P}\p{S}]`.

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/ifiX61):

```java
String s = "Пожалуйста,помогите!";
Pattern slovaPattern = Pattern.compile("(?U)[^\\W_]+");
Matcher matcherSlova = slovaPattern.matcher(s);
List<String> slova = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcherSlova.find()){
    slova.add(matcherSlova.group(0)); 
} 
System.out.println(slova);
System.out.println("Кол-во слов: " + Integer.toString(slova.size()));
// => [Пожалуйста, помогите]
// => Кол-во слов: 2
        
Pattern znakiPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\p{P}\\p{S}]");
Matcher matcherZnaki = znakiPattern.matcher(s);
List<String> znaki = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcherZnaki.find()){
    znaki.add(matcherZnaki.group(0)); 
} 
System.out.println(znaki);
System.out.println("Кол-во пунктуационных символов: " + Integer.toString(znaki.size()));
// => [,, !]
// => Кол-во пунктуационных символов: 2
```

Если многоточие в виде трёх последовательных точек учитывать как один пунктуационный знак, замените `"[\\p{P}\\p{S}]"` на `"\\.{3}|[\\p{P}\\p{S}]"`.

Если нужно искать только буквенные слова, замените `"(?U)[^\\W_]+"` на `"\\p{L}+"` или `"(?U)\\b\\p{L}+\\b"` (если справа и слева не должно быть букв, цифр и знака подчёркивания).